# VIM Search and replace contents between square brackets

Tags: regex, vim

I need to replace contents in square bracket with \ while preserving the contents in the bracket.

eg : string

```
[.\*][.\*][.\*]
```

to be replaced with string

```
\\[.\*\\]\\[.\*\\][.*]
```

Given the following line :

```
abcdef[0][box][21]
```

I need to replace it with

```
abcdef\\[0\\]\\[box\\][21]
```

Comment: @romainl, there was only a single \ before editing this question.

Comment: I know, probably because OP doesn't know how markdown is supposed to work. Let's wait for them to come back and fix their backticks.

Comment: @romainl, ok, let's wait.

Answer (score 3):

VIM command search and replace all occurrence of `[ ]` to `\[ \]`:

```
syntax: %s/pattern/replacement/flags
```

Command

```
:%s/\(\[\|\]\)/\\\1/g
```

Pattern Explanation

`:%s` makes it work on the whole file, rather than just the current line.

`\(\[\|\]\)` :

- `\(` starting of group
- `\[` escaped opening square bracket
- `\|` OR operator
- `\]` escaped closing square bracket
- `\)` end of pattern group

`\\\1` : Replace previous captured group with \[ or \]

`/g`: Replace all occurrences in the line